# NodeJS object DNS API service prototype

Tags: node.js, api, api-design

I'd like to write a basic *DNS API service* using NodeJS; I have an external (black-boxed) *service* that both generates random URL(s) as access points: `https://<host_name>/<UUID>` and pushes these URL(s) to my service.

I would like a way to link these URL(s) with static names that a user can create (upon registration). The idea is that users would be able to generate a *static keys* (unique identifiers) and use these "keys" (unique-identifiers) to access (by redirection) a given URL; for example, suppose that the temporary link ( one of the ones that is being pushed into my DNS service) looks like this: `http://cool_server/2938ba6e-e54e-4393-926f-dacc91c2a33e` (the UUID keeps changing every x number of minutes), the user creates an account on my object_DNS_service and generates a static key (or string that is unique): *link_to_cool_server*.

I would like my DNS service to link `http://cool_server/2938ba6e-e54e-4393-926f-dacc91c2a33e` to `http(s)://link_to_cool_server.<my_host_name>`such that no matter how often that URL that is being pushed into my service changes, a user would be able to still access it by redirection, using my own host-name and their unique key/string:

*My question is:* would the DNS module in NodeJS be able to help me solve this problem? - how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use wildcard dns on `<my_host_name>` such that `<anything>.<my_host_name>` resolves to the ip address of your node server
2. There will be a single endpoint/route on that node server which pulls the `<key>` out of the url `https://<key>.<my_host_name>`
3. The endpoint then looks up the current UUID for `<key>` in your database
4. Responds to the request with a redirect to `https://cool_server/<UUID>`

Comment: This is helpful, actually: (up-voted): how would you tackle the re-direct? just a 308 status code?

Comment: If you're using express it's even easier, just `res.redirect(uuidUrl)`